# Javascript classList.add.toggle not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

the classList works fine, but it dont want to toggle, just adding the class

```
<script>
    const pencet = document.getElementById('butn')
    const keluar = document.getElementById('kiri')

    pencet.addEventListener('click', show())

    function show() {
        keluar.classList.toggle('show');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you probably need to give more context about how show is being invoked and how you know the class isn't being toggled.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pencet = document.getElementById('butn')
const keluar = document.getElementById('kiri')

pencet.addEventListener('click', show())

function show() {
    keluar.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

`show` function is called immediately you need to pass it as callback. You need to remove `()` after `show` like this

```js
const pencet = document.getElementById('butn')
const keluar = document.getElementById('kiri')

pencet.addEventListener('click', show) // remove `()` here

function show() {
    keluar.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

if you want only want to add `show` class even when the class is exist and not remove class if exist you can use `add` instead of `toggle`

```js
keluar.classList.add('show');
```

Comment: thank you so much, you really helped me. i didn't notice that mistake